# Is mutex needed for different offsets into allocated heap memory

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, mutex

I am laying in the framework for a tool that will generate a binary data table.  I a plan on making this multithreaded to take full advantage of the 24 cores at my disposal.  (I am estimating that the wall time for generation of the data will be about 50 days–in a single thread.).  I have done this in the past using server/client design with socket communication as I needed to distributed this across multiple machines.

This time around, I am looking at a single machine/multi-threaded approach and am trying to figure out how to do this the right way.

The master thread will handle the assignment of tasks to each child thread and determining the offset into the allocated memory.

Each thread will write to a unique address range within the allocated memory.  Because these blocks will never overlap between records, no two threads will ever attempt to write the same offset.

[image: {Meta Data}{Rec1}{Rec2}{Rec3}{Rec4}{...}{...}{...}]

```
void computeRecord(void *taskInput)
{
  struct TaskData *taskData = (TaskData *)(taskInput);

  RecordData data; 
  // A huge long computation block to populate data
  //   (4-5 second run time)

  long record_id = taskData->record_id;
  char *buffer   = taskData->start_buffer;

  // mutex lock needed here ??

  int n_bytes = sizeof(RecordData)
  memcpy( (char *)(buffer+record_id*n_bytes), (char *)(&recordData) n_bytes);

  // mutex unlock here ?
}
```

Long setup.  Short question.  Is the mutex necessary in this case?

Comment: I don't think it's needed, but there might be some subtleties so I will not answer.

Comment: I would not want a 50 compute-day task to live entirely in memory myself.  That level of compute:bits generated should be easy to save out to disk without hurting bandwidth, which then permits partial runs to be collected easily, and separate consumption from production.  To your question, however, no mutex should be needed if your offsets are reasonably aligned on most architectures.

Comment: Have you thought using OpenMP: it's exacty the kind of parallelism it is designed to address

Comment: What calculation is so slow? Just curious.

Comment: @Yakk,  Note that by multithreading on 24 cores, the wall clock time should come down to more like 2 real days.  That being said, I do plan on checkpointing my data every hour or so (for which I'm thinking I will use a semaphore to halting all the threads before writing out the buffer).

Comment: @Christophe.  I have absolutely no say in what frameworks or tools can be introduced into my development environment.  I have to live with what has been chosen for us by our IT security team.

Comment: @Joonazan.  This is an optimization problem over a 15 dimensional space with highly non-linear constraints.  There are over a million records in the table, each taking roughly 5 seconds to compute.

Comment: @Yakk,   Would the answer to my original question change if I used a memory mapped file rather than memory on the heap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For best performance, you'll want your data to be aligned to cache-lines - this will avoid the different CPU cores from "bouncing" cache-lines between each other.

But regardless of that, as long as we are talking separate bytes that are interacted on independently, no protection is needed. Only if more than one thread is accessing the very same byte [also applies when accessing multiple bytes, of course].

<strike>Edit: This statement is of course only true if the processor has byte addressing. The processor that comes to mind that doesn't is Alpha, but there may be others.</strike>
(Edit2: No, doesn't matter in C++11 compliant compiler, it's up to the compiler to deal with byte addressing in a thread-safe manner)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have control over the structure of the data table (or the records contained therein.  I am generating data for an application that defines the interface into the data.

Comment: You are asserting there are no processors where memory read/writes are bigger than a byte at a time?

Comment: @Yakk: Correct, and I have added a statement to that effect.

Comment: Writing to two different addresses in a multi threaded program is well defined by the standard. If a CPU cannot do byte addressing the compiler has to worry about what to do. Anything else would make it impossible to ever write correct programs

Comment: @Voo: I think it's a bit of both. Completely independent data¸ yes, it's the compilers problem. If we have, say, a very large array of bytes, and want to write data from multiple threads to bytes that are next to each other (and in the same machine-word), then it becomes the programmers problem to ensure that only one thread can write to that region at a time. But for x86 and ARM, I know for sure it's not a problem.

Comment: @Mats You're saying that if you have `char[10] arr;` and one thread writing to `arr[0]` and one to `arr[1]` then the standard would qualify this is undefined? That goes completely against my understanding of how the C++  standard defines data races. `arr[0]` and `arr[1]` are two separate memory locations to my understanding, any links or preferably standard language on that?

Comment: [Question on the topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34706564/writing-to-different-offsets-in-array-always-well-defined/34706615?noredirect=1#34706615): The consensus so far seems to be that the compiler is responsible for making sure that writes to different offsets are handled correctly.

Comment: The compiler is responsible for "not overwriting arr[1] when you write to arr[0] and vice versa". However, it is NOT responsible for making sure those operations are atomic in a multithreaded environment. If that is what you require, then specific atomic operations or some form of locking is required, and outside of what the compiler will in itself generate - this applies if the processor itself can not individually access `arr[n]` without writing to other cells. The cache maintenance on modern processors will ensure that writes to that cell is honoured when the processor can write to it.

Comment: @Matt Sure if you have actual race conditions in the code itself you have to protect against them (i.e. reading the same array location in one thread while writing in another). My point was just that `arr[0] = 1` and `arr[1] = 1` in two different threads is well defined. The way I understand your edit is that you're disagreeing with this. The statement above your edit is always true as long as the compiler implements the C++11 or higher standard even on Alpha (and the c++ committee explicitly pointed out alphas as one CPU where this decision would lead to performance degradation).

Comment: @Voo: Do you have a source for that? As I don't believe that IS true. The compiler will not produce atomics or mutexes for every byte-operation that could be performed by different threads [consider `void func(char *arr, int i) { arr[i] = 1; }` called from multiple threads with distinct but nearby values of `i`, on a machine that doesn't have byte-sized instructions, e.g. Alpha)

Comment: @Mats My earlier linked question on SO. [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34706564/writing-to-different-offsets-in-array-always-well-defined?noredirect=1#comment57160841_34706564). Also in particular [N2746: Rationale for the C++ working paper definition of memory location](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2746.html) which explicitly points out the problems with Alpha CPUs and the definition.

Comment: @Everyone.  In addition to the huge thanks for all the input on my question, an even bigger thanks for validating that this was not a "stupid newbie" question as there appears to be some nuance to the answer.