# Writing to different offsets in array always well defined

Tags: c++, multithreading, language-lawyer, c++14

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34700940/144746) question it was brought up that writing to two different offsets in a char array concurrently would imply a data race, since some processors such as Alpha don't have byte-wise addressing so it'd be hard to implement this.

I certainly see that this would very much slow down writing bytes on alpha processors (basically involving a LL/SC), but as I understand the C++ standard every field in an array is its own memory location (although from reading §1.7, I could also see the whole array as one memory location - that's probably what this question boils down to).

So basically is the following pseudo code

```
char arr[10]; // global field
Thread 1:
arr[1] = 0;
Thread 2:
arr[0] = 1;
```

well defined according to the C++14 standard or not?

Comment: Relevant links: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM/DataRaces http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2746.html

Comment: @ninjali N2746 is the perfect answer to the question. It explains the decision and also addresses Alpha explicitly (basically yes there would be performance degradations for ancient alpha CPUs, but we don't care too much about discontinued CPUs that are known for being insane). The additional considerations that went into the decision and what it implies are very interesting too. I'd accept your answer if you included that link and gave a short summary of the main points.

Comment: Those papers do not appear to address Alpha's capability for per-processor physical address locking – if CPU _A_ load-locks an address with the intention of doing a read-modify-write (e.g. updating one byte of a word), and CPU _B_ stores to that address before _A_, then when _A_ tries to do its store (write) it will fail and branch back to the load and attempt again until it succeeds. Think CAS loops. It seems to me all the compiler has to do is load-lock any containing word when doing byte writes and the CPU will take care of the rest...

Comment: @ildjarn Yes a simple ll/sc will work, but the performance overhead would be enormous.

Comment: Ah, apologies, it wasn't obvious to me what 'LL/SC' meant in your post; obviously you've already addressed this. Though I have to wonder (not having had personal experience with an Alpha) what the lock overhead is when there's little-to-no contention...

Comment: @ildjarn Well rule #1 for writing good papers, always write out your acronyms on first use, so really my fault for not expanding on ll/sc (load-linked/store-conditional, allowing similar things to what CAS does on x86). And not sure either (no experience with Alpha, although ARM uses the same instructions), but doing atomic instructions on x86 costs you at least one, but possibly two cache misses, so several hundred cycles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the C++14 standard (1.7/3):

> Two or more threads of execution (1.10) can update and access separate memory locations without interfering with each other.

Where it previously defines (emphasis mine)

> A memory location is either an object of **scalar** type or a maximal sequence of adjacent bit-fields all having
>   non-zero width.

So the `char`s of the array are memory locations, but the array itself is not; therefore, separate threads writing to different `char`s do not interfere with each other.

Comment: But if you don't tell the compiler multiple threads are going to work on the array, how will it know to avoid optimizations that introduce data races? IIRC, you have to make those memory locations `atomic`, shouldn't you?

Comment: @eran No. From this answer, as long as you can guarantee that every thread reads and writes disjoint fields, the compiler is responsible for making sure nothing breaks. But yes, the followup question is then: How do compilers for processors without byte-addressing handle writes to byte arrays efficiently under C++14. Per my personal policy I won't accept the answer for another 6 hours or so, to give other people time to chime in but  this seems fine to me.

Comment: @eran: It does seem like it would be impossible to optimize in general, but if the compiler could determine that no other thread has access to the array it could do more optimization.  For example, if the array was a local variable, and no pointers to the array were stored to memory outside the function or passed to other functions, then it could assume that no other thread had access to the array.

Comment: Hence C's `restrict`.

Comment: @ildjarn I tried to understand the formal definition of restrict in C11, but pretty much gave up. Does `restrict` in C11 now also mean that not only nothing aliases, but also that no other thread accesses it?

Comment: @Voo : If nothing aliases, then how _could_ another thread access it?

Comment: @ildjarn I always assumed it meant "nothing aliases in the scope", because   in `void foo() { char a[10]; bar(a);} void bar(restrict char *x) {}` a and x both alias the same memory location. Now if bar was called in two different threads, in bar itself nothing could alias, but the two threads could write to the same location still.

Comment: @Voo : Indeed, scope is the key, and you wouldn't necessarily put `restrict` on the function parameter, but likely higher up at the scope passing the function argument, or even where the object is created.

Comment: @Voo : In any case, `restrict` is a declaration of intent to the compiler, purely for optimization purposes, and if your code does alias then you get UB. It's not there to prevent aliasing, it's there to tell the optimizer that it can safely optimize to its heart's content.

Comment: @ildjarn I agree that it probably wouldn't be useful, but the question is what the compiler can and cannot assume. Is `void foo() { char a[10]; RunInThread(() -> bar(a)); RunInThread(() -> bar(a)); } void bar(restrict char*){}` valid (I hope the pseudo code is clear) or not? To me I'd assume it is, since inside `bar` nothing aliases with it.

Comment: @Voo : That's UB, since you're lying to the compiler by aliasing when the function declaration says you cannot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100295/discussion-between-voo-and-ildjarn).